# Как заливать и удалять файлы с FTPS сервера, используя Swift

Tags: swift, ftp

Всем привет! Появилась такая задача -

Необходимо на Swift написать метод загрузки файлов(фото, аудио) на FTPS сервер, а также возможность их удалять. Есть ли такая возможность?